# How can we find and replace words while matching two text files?

Tags: string, awk, sed, replace

I have two word databases in different formats for two different dictionaries. One of them includes a hyphenated version of each word (e.g. `ad‧mi‧ra‧tion` for `admiration`) while the other does not. My goal is to replace the unhyphenated words in the latter with the hyphenated ones.

Let's say we have

```
admiration
<span class="INFLX" >admiration</span><span class="HYPHENATION" >ad‧mi‧ra‧tion</span>
</>
```

in `source1.txt` and

```
admiration    
<a style="color: darkblue; text-decoration: none" href="sound://admiration_Uk.spx">[UK] admiration</a>
</>
```

in `source2.txt`.

We would like to produce

```
admiration    
<a style="color: darkblue; text-decoration: none" href="sound://admiration_Uk.spx">[UK] ad‧mi‧ra‧tion</a>
</>
```

in `output.txt`.

Basically the expected output is `source2.txt` with hyphenation added to the word. `sed -i s/<original text>/<replaced text>/g source1.txt` will be able to find and replace strings in a single file. However, how could we match the data entry and replace the string `source2.txt` with that in `source1.txt`?

Will tools or commands such as `sed` or `awk` be able to compare two files and replace the strings? Otherwise, could we have a program doing such task?

Comment: Can there be some other strings like `[UK]` around the hyphenated word?

Comment: I think so, as long as the hyphenated word is shown in the final output.